# ggplot2 will not let me change the linetype to "longdash"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot with multiple different curves that each have a different linetype with ggplot2 and the lines always show up as solid.

I have tried using linetype = "longdash" and linetype = 6. I have also tried putting the linetype inside and outside the aes() and I've tried using scale_linetype_manual(). Nothing is working currently and every time I try to plot the data, it gives me a solid line. I have also tried updating ggplot2 using install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE). I'll include my code below and the plot that I am trying to replicate.

```
ggplot(simu_dat, aes(tset)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = N.simu1), color="plum", linetype = 1, alpha=0.4, linewidth = 4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = S.simu1), color="blue4", linetype = 1, alpha=0.4, linewidth = 4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = I.simu1), color="deeppink", linetype = 1, alpha=0.4, linewidth = 4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = R.simu1), color="springgreen", linetype = 1, alpha=0.4, linewidth = 4) +

  geom_line(aes(y = S.simu2), color="blue4", linetype = 6, linewidth = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = I.simu2), color="deeppink", linetype = 6, linewidth = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = R.simu2), color="springgreen", linetype = 6, linewidth = 2)
```

[Here is the plot I'm trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2IAn.jpg)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What version of ggplot2 are you using? If I test with `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_line(linetype=2)` i definitely see a non-solid line. Are you viewing the plot in RStudio? Or saving to a graphics device?

Comment: 6 is "twodash", not longdash ... that's `linetype=5`. If you want to stick with numerical line types, see `expand.grid(x=1:2, y=1:6) |> ggplot(aes(x, factor(y))) + geom_line(aes(group=y, linetype=I(y)))`. You can see more at `vignette("ggplot2-specs", package="ggplot2")` aka https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html

Answer (score 2):

`linetype=6` is `"twodash"`, and `linetype=5` is `"longdash"`. You can look at [`vignette("ggplot2-specs", package="ggplot2")`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html) to see

> An integer or name: 0 = blank, 1 = solid, 2 = dashed, 3 = dotted, 4 = dotdash, 5 = longdash, 6 = twodash, as shown below:
>
> ```
> lty <- c("solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", "longdash", "twodash")
> linetypes <- data.frame(
>   y = seq_along(lty),
>   lty = lty
> ) 
> ggplot(linetypes, aes(0, y)) +
>   geom_segment(aes(xend = 5, yend = y, linetype = lty)) + 
>   scale_linetype_identity() + 
>   geom_text(aes(label = lty), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.2) +
>   scale_x_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) + 
>   scale_y_reverse(NULL, breaks = NULL)
> ```
>
> [image]

However, I suggest altering your code to work in a "long format". I don't have your data, but I think this is a good start for pivoting and adapting your code. (I'll show `tidyr::pivot_longer`, though this can be done about as easily with `reshape2::melt` and, with more work, `stats::reshape`.)

```r
aesthestics <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ name, ~ color, ~ linetype, ~ linewidth, ~ alpha
  , "N.simu1", "plum", 1, 4, 0.4
  , "S.simu1", "blue4", 1, 4, 0.4
  , "I.simu1", "deeppink", 1, 4, 0.4
  , "R.simu1", "springgreen", 1, 4, 0.4
  , "S.simu2", "blue4", 5, 2, 1
  , "I.simu2", "deeppink", 5, 2, 1
  , "R.simu2", "springgreen", 5, 2, 1
)
pivot_longer(simu_dat, cols = -tset) |>
  # just in case, I don't know if you have more columns,
  # may not be necessary
  subset(name %in% aesthetics$name) |>
  ggplot(aes(tset, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name, linetype = name, linewidth = name, alpha = name)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(aesthetics$color, aesthetics$name)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = setNames(aesthetics$linetype, aesthetics$name)) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(values = setNames(aesthetics$linewidth, aesthetics$name)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = setNames(aesthetics$alpha, aesthetics$name))
```

or slightly more broken-out

```r
aes_ltrs <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ ltr, ~ color,
  , "N.simu1", "plum"
  , "S.simu1", "blue4"
  , "I.simu1", "deeppink"
  , "R.simu1", "springgreen"
  , "S.simu2", "blue4"
  , "I.simu2", "deeppink"
  , "R.simu2", "springgreen"
)
aes_sims <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ sim, ~ linetype, ~ linewidth, ~ alpha
  , "1", 1, 4, 0.4
  , "2", 5, 2, 1
)
dplyr::select(simu_dat, tset, matches("[NSIR]\\.simu[12]")) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -tset, names_pattern = "([A-Z]+)\\.simu([0-9])",
               names_to = c("letter", "sim")) |>
  ggplot(aes(tset, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = ltr, color = ltr, linetype = sim, linewidth = sim, alpha = sim)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(aes_ltrs$color, aes_ltrs$ltr)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = setNames(aes_sims$linetype, aes_sims$sim)) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(values = setNames(aes_sims$linewidth, aes_sims$sim)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = setNames(aes_sims$alpha, aes_sims$sim))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. To give some context for my data, I am running multiple different simulations of a population infected with parasites. N.simu1, S.simu1, I.simu1, R.simu1 represent the total pop, the susceptible pop, the infected pop, and the recovered pop for simulation 1 and so on for three other simulations. I used gather to make the data long. Do I use the ggplot code you provided as is, or do I need to sub in something for values and name? (I'm referring to the second chunk of code). Thank you for your help!!

Comment: `gather` has been deprecated for a few years, I suggest shifting from `gather` to `pivot_longer`. Given, the names "should" work. You didn't share any data, so it's inference, but give it a try! It might just work as-is :-)

Comment: But ... to be safe, run the `pivot_longer` and save the result and look at the resulting frame. In the case of the first `pivot` code block above, you should have columns `tset`, `name`, and `value`; in the second, you should have `tset`, `letter`, `sim`, and `value`. If they are different, my mistake, but just update the plotting code to reflect the appropriate column.